Using Java RMI and Reflection for a Broker without interface
I'm attempting to develop a broker in Java. Currently, I have created a server capable of posting it's services within the broker. Additionally, I have implemented a client that can invoke methods on the server via the broker. Upon receiving the result, the server forwards it to the broker, which then delivers it to the requesting client. Notably, the client, broker, and server operate on distinct hardware. I aim to avoid the necessity of a server Interface class shared with the broker, if possible. While the current implementation relies on this shared Interface class, I intend to explore an alternative approach utilizing Java Reflection.
This is my server try without the interface:
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Server2 extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Remote {
    private static String serverName = "Server2647";
    private static String hostName;
    
    private String magazineName;
    private int numberOfArticles;

    public Server2() throws RemoteException {
        this.numberOfArticles++;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) throws RemoteException {
        this.magazineName = name;
    }

    public void addArticle() throws RemoteException {
        this.numberOfArticles++;
    }
    
    public String getName() throws RemoteException {
        return this.magazineName;
    }
    
    public int getArticles() throws RemoteException {
        return this.numberOfArticles;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Set the directory where the java.policy file is located
        // The second argument is the path to the java.policy
        System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "./java.policy");
        // Create security manager
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        // Name or IP of the host where the server object resides
        String IP = args[0];
        String port = args[1];
        
        // Server address
        hostName = IP + ":" + port; 
        // Broker address
        String brokerHostName = args[2];
        try {

            Server2 server = new Server2();
            System.out.println(serverName + " created");

            Naming.rebind("//" + hostName +  "/" + serverName, server);

            BrokerInterface broker = (BrokerInterface) Naming.lookup("//" + brokerHostName + "Broker647");
            
            broker.register_server(serverName, hostName);
            System.out.println("Server registered.");
            // Vector with all the server services and if they are registered
            Map<Service, Boolean> services = new LinkedHashMap<>();

            services.put(new Service(serverName, hostName, "setName", new Vector() {{ add(String.class); }}, "void"), true);
            services.put(new Service(serverName, hostName, "addArticle", new Vector(), "void"), true);
            services.put(new Service(serverName, hostName, "getName", new Vector(), "String"), true);
            services.put(new Service(serverName, hostName, "getArticles", new Vector(), "int"), true);

            // Iterate over entries using entrySet() method
            for (Map.Entry<Service, Boolean> entry : services.entrySet()) {
                // Get the service
                Service s = entry.getKey();
                // Register
                if (services.get(s)) {
                    Vector parameters = new Vector();
                    parameters.addAll(s.getParam());
                    // void register_service(String serverName, String serviceName, Vector<Class> parameterList, String return_type)
                    broker.register_service(serverName,s.getName(),parameters, s.getReturn());
                }

            }

            List<Service> serviceList = new ArrayList<>(services.keySet());

            Boolean terminate = false;
            while (!terminate) {
                showServices(services);
                System.out.println("Enter service number to modify or 'end' to finish");


                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                String input = scanner.nextLine();

                try {
                    if (input.equals("end")) {
                        terminate = true;
                    } else {
                        int index = Integer.parseInt(input.trim());

                        if (index >  services.size()) {
                            System.out.println("Select an index that appears on the screen.");
                        } else {
                            Service modification = serviceList.get(index);

                            Boolean state = services.get(modification);

                            if (state) {
                                broker.deregister_service(serverName, modification.getName());
                            } else {
                                Vector parameters = new Vector();
                                parameters.addAll(modification.getParam());

                                broker.register_service(serverName, modification.getName(), parameters, modification.getReturn());
                            }

                            services.put(modification, !state);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("Input should be an integer or 'end'.");
                }

                System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");  
                System.out.flush();
            }

            for (Map.Entry<Service, Boolean> entry : services.entrySet()) {
                // Get the service
                Service s = entry.getKey();
                // Mark the service as unregistered
                entry.setValue(false);

                broker.deregister_service(serverName, s.getName());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void showServices(Map<Service, Boolean> services) {
        System.out.println("The server services are as follows:");

        int index = 0;

        for (Map.Entry<Service, Boolean> entry : services.entrySet()) {
            // Get the service
            Service s = entry.getKey();
            // Whether it is active or not
            boolean currentValue = entry.getValue();
            System.out.println(index + " Registration of service " + s.getName() + " : " + currentValue);
            index++;
        }
    }
}


And the method that the broker uses to execute the service:
public Response execute_service(Vector service_parameters)
        throws MalformedURLException, RemoteException, NotBoundException,
        NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException
        {
        Object server = (Object) Naming.lookup("//"+ this.remote_host_IP_port + "/" + this.server_name);
        
        Class serverClass = server.getClass();
        
    if(parameter_list.size() == 0){
        Method method = serverClass.getMethod(service_name);
        
        return new Response(method.invoke(server));
        
        }else{
            Method method = serverClass.getMethod(service_name, parameter_list.getClass());


        Vector<Object> parameters = new Vector<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < service_parameters.size(); i++) {
            Class<?> paramType = parameter_list.get(i);
            
            try {
            Object convertedParam = convertToType((String) service_parameters.get(i), paramType);
            parameters.add(convertedParam);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.err.println("Parameter " + i + " could not be transformed: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
            }
        }
        
        for (Object element : parameters) {
            Class<?> type = element.getClass();
            System.out.println("Data type: " + type.getName());
        }
        
        try {
            return new Response(method.invoke(server, parameters));
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            Throwable cause = e.getCause();
            cause.printStackTrace(); 
            return null;
        }
        }
    }


Here the auxiliary method:
private Object convertToType(String value, Class<?> targetType) {
    if (targetType == String.class) {
        return value;
    } else if (targetType == Integer.class || targetType == int.class) {
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(value);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not transform to int: " + value, e);
        }
    } 

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported parameter type " + targetType.getName());
}


The error occurs within the method execute_service, when I try to get the method from the reflected class
Method method = serverClass.getMethod(service_name);

The error thrown is this:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.getArticles()

If I put a Server Interface on the Broker side that exposes the server methods it works. But I want to avoid this.

As you can see, the object delivered via the Registry is not the server object, it is a dynamic proxy. It is constructed so as to implement all the remote methods of the server object, which in this case is none, as the only remote interface the server implements is Remote, which is empty. You will have to reconsider your design. For example you are deriving no benefit from extending UnicastRemoteObject.

NB What is BrokerInterface ? and parameter_list? And why are you using Vector that was deprecated 25 years ago? It seems to me that you probably want to make execute_service a remote method, but there could be much more to it than that.

This question makes no sense, and much important details are missing. From what you have shown you have two rmi servers. Server+Broker and both are clients of each other. You've exported Server class directly, not its stub. The RMI registry / naming lookups depends on having proxy classes in the client - but if client doesn't have the server interface then it won't be able to receive a client side proxy class matching the interface of the server.

@DuncG (1) 'You've exported Server class directly, not its stub' is not correct. UnicastRemoteObject serialization takes care of that.  (2) 'The RMI registry / naming lookups depends on having proxy classes in the client' isn't correct either. Here the client was 'able [to] receive a client ide proxy class matching the interface of the server': the problem was that that interface contained zero methods.

@user207421 1) Good point. 2) Isn't it broken either way if the interface is not available to the client classloader? Without "Server implements Whatever" there won't be method for the client (as NoSuchMethodException observed here). Adding "implements Whatever" means that Naming.lookup will fail to unmarshall the interface class for use in the proxy client class (as ClassNotFoundException).

@DuncG Of course, but that’s not the issue here.

The whole point of RMI is to hide the marshalling of calls and reflective invocations. When you are going to reimplement this logic, there is no benefit in using RMI. Just define your own protocol.
